# How to change the Color of text in UITabBarItem in iOS 4

Tags: ios4, uitabbar, uicolor, uitabbaritem

I know iOS 5 and later has methods to change the attributes for `UITabBarItem` but i don't know how to change the color of `UITabBarItem` title in iOS less than 5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't be set in iOS4 as far as I know. However, you can customize your tabBar to do so. You can try [THIS](https://github.com/boctor/idev-recipes/tree/master/CustomTabBar). It works excellent. ;)

And an interesting post : [Customising the Appearance of UITabBarController](http://praxisstalled.blogspot.com.es/2010/08/customising-appearance-of.html)